# What does [Authorize(Users = "*")] mean in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What does `[Authorize(Users = "*")]` mean in asp.net mvc.? Also please explain `[Authorize(Users = "")]` and `[Authorize(Users = "?")].`

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To authorize all users, just omit using the `[Authorize]` attribute alltogether. To authorize authenticated users, use the `[Authorize]` attribute. To authorize specific roles or users, that is when you'll have `[Authorize (Users = "someuser")]` or `[Authorize (Roles = "somerole")]`.

Comment: I tried [Authorize(Users = "*")] to a Action. It does not even allow authenticated users. When i add just [Authorize], it allows the authenticated users.

Comment: The `[Authorize]` attribute alone is to authorize authenticated users, that is correct.

Comment: The start (`*`) must just be for config authorization rules, it's possible it isn't recognized in the attribute as a valid value.

Comment: To authorize all users, just omit using the `[Authorize]` attribute alltogether.  To authorize authenticated users, use the `[Authorize]` attribute.  To authorize specific roles or users, that is when you'll have `[Authorize (Users = "someuser")]` or `[Authorize (Roles = "somerole")]`.

Comment: Thanks folks. I fell into the same pitfall as the OP

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [documentation for the attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) it doesn't look like you can use it that way. By default the AuthorizeAttribute only allows access to authenticated and authorised users so passing `*` (all) or `?` (guest) doesn't make sense.
The Users property is used to further restrict the list of authenticated users who can access the Action method along with the Roles property which can also be used to further filter any authenticated access.

Comment: A peculiar thing is that when i use [Authorize(Users = "")] , it just allows authenticated users.

Answer (score 0):

I think the second post is correct, in `[Authorize(Users = " * ")]`  the `" * "` part doesn't make any sense (in the `web.config` it does but that is something completely different).