# ASP.NET MVC application that uses forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I am going to take Microsoft 70-486 (MVC) exam. So i am preparing for it. Came across one most important question asking in 70-486 exam but does not satisfied with the answer they given.

**The Question**

You are developing an ASP.NET MVC application that uses forms authentication.
The user database contains a user named `LibraryAdmin`.

You have the following requirements:

- You must allow all users to access the `GetBook` method.
- You must restrict access to the `EditBook` method to the user named `LibraryAdmin`.

You need to implement the controller to meet the requirements.

Which code segment should you use? (Each correct answer presents a complete solution. Choose all that apply.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

But According to question **i must restrict restrict access to the EditBook method to the user named `LibraryAdmin`** Both Option A and C will allow acces to Edit Book. So i feel the answer is wrong. Then what is correct answer?

ref: [From DOCUMENT](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B88_6d1RUOE2WDkwTTZiYTBzOWs/edit)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I THNK you got  the meaning of the sentence wrong. This i conclude after reading [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23426766/asp-net-mvc-application-that-uses-forms-authentication#comment35902320_23426864) on DarthVaders [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23426864/1182982).

Eg: **restrict access of editing this question to Ryder** means only Ryder should be able to edit this question. and not the other way round.

Answer (score 2):

Yes A and C are correct.

in A GetBookis open to any user with `AllowAnon` attribute. Then `[Authorize(Users="..")]`. This is correct.

Likewise in C code is checking user by accessing User Identity directly and checking username with LibraryAdmin. This is fine too.

Book's answers are correct.
See : [What does [Authorize(Users = "*")] mean in asp.net mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082754/what-does-authorizeusers-mean-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: ya u ryt. but in option A they given [Authorize(User="LibraryAdmin")] it will allow LibraryAdmin to access that method. but acccording to question i must restrict access to him. so oly i doubted. can u explain me it.

Answer (score 0):

If you  read the question carefully  you must allow

1. Access all users to access the  method "Getbook"

2.And "LibraryAdmin" for the method  'Editbook' and restrict other user by all means.

Looking  the option A and C these options satisfies the above conditions so answer would be option 'A' and 'C'

Answer (score 0):

Both will work but If you have to chose only one option then "**A**" is appropriate answer, Because we can neglect option "C" **why there is [Authorize] Data Annotation over both class and function**. if we are using it over class name then no need to write on function.

Answer (score -1):

You have the following requirements:

1. You must allow all users to access the GetBook method.
2. You must restrict access to the EditBook method to the user named LibraryAdmin.

Answer should be **A**

C is incorrect because the user named LibraryAdmin is given access to EditBook action when the requirement is to restrict access.

Either the question is wrong or the answers provided in the book are wrong.

Comment: But in "A" LibraryAdmin also has permission to the EditBook method right?
I think meaning of "restrict access to LibraryAdmin" means that he gets rights, as in A. So it's A+C